# A Generic classmethod "print" that prints the element in an object collection

Tags: java, generics, printing

```
public static <T> void print(Collection<T> l)
```

If I have a collection containing a, b and c I want the output to be

```
[a,b,c]
```

and if its empty i want it to be

```
[]
```

My code now.

```
public class CollectionOps {
public static <E, T extends Iterable<E>> void print(T a){
    //for(Iterable type Iterable element : collection)
    for (E x : a) {
        System.out.print(x);

    }

}
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    a.add("a");
    a.add("b");
    a.add("c");
    print(a);
}
```

}

Output :`abc`

Maybe I could use System.out.printf() somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Collection classes usually override `toString` to produce exactly that output. Therefore if you have a `Collection` you can just do

```
System.out.println(collection);
```

This works because `println` calls `toString`.

If you want to print an `Iterable` in that form, I would just make it a collection.

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object o : iterable)
    list.add(o);
System.out.println(list);
```

Also note that you can improve your method signature by using a wildcard.

```
public static void print(Iterable<?> iterable)
```

Comment: I want to make my own toString @Paul Boddington

Answer (score 1):

Most of Java collections (List, Set, Queue, etc') implement `toString` method exactly as you want it. So why not just use it ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    print(Arrays.asList('a','b','c'));
    print(new ArrayList());
    print(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a","b","c")));
    print(new HashSet());
    print(new PriorityQueue<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)));
    print(new PriorityQueue<>());
}

public static <T> void print(Collection<T> l){
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

Output:

```
[a, b, c]
[]
[a, b, c]
[]
[1, 2, 3]
[]
```